# Are there any official rules for Dragonborn in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dragonborn

We are currently converting a 4E game to Pathfinder and one of the current PCs is a Dragonborn. Does the race (or an equivalent) exist as a player race in any official supplement / product?

Google turns up a lot of house rule attempts to port it over from varying years, but nothing from Paizo that I can spot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no direct analogue.  The closest might be the [Nagaji](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-nagaji) from the Advanced Race Guide - but you can browse [all the official races on the SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races) and see what might capture dragonborn-age the most to you.

Answer (score 5):

There is a section in the back of the Advanced Race Guide for the creation of new races. You just need to come up with a set of abilities that match what the 4th Ed version gives you. I converted a "Draconic" character from 3.5 and I talked through what I got with the DM:

**Racial Qualities**
Humanoid (Draconic) 0pt
Size = Medium 0pt
Speed = normal 0pt
Ability = +2 stats x 2 2pt
Langauges = standard = 0pt

**Racial Traits**
Immunities +4 vs Sleep and paralysis = 2pt
Natural Armour +1 = 2pt
Skill +2 intimidate and Perception = 4pt
2 Claw attacks (d4) = 2pt
Lowlight / Darknvision = 3 pts

**Total** = 15pts which was a little high but the DM was happy enough.

Generally just allowing a player to min/max with his class is bad idea, but working together to come up with something generic is good.